# Postgres - A SQL Query to Retrieve Specific Table Names

Tags: sql, postgresql

Against a Postgres DB, I have a need to retrieve, for a specific schema SCHEMA_A, the names of all BASE_TABLES whose names start with FOO. I can successfully use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables;
```

I just need it further constrained to be only BASE_TABLES starting with FOO. By the way, to the extent possible, I want to use generic SQL.

Comment: What do you mean with "generic SQL"?

Comment: see: [Difference between information_schema.tables and pg_tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431104/difference-between-information-schema-tables-and-pg-tables)  (Which probably means that you can only do it with generic-postgresql-sql )

Comment: I mean to avoid usng PSQL specific syntax, if possible. Not sure whether it is or not.

Comment: I don't think these are pg_tables because none of them start with pg_ ? Is that by definition a pg_table?If so, then I am only concerned with information_schema_tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sure if I am missing something, but wouldn't that be a simple:

```
select *
from information_schema.tables
where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  and table_name like 'foo%'
```